# Is there any replay value in the Curse of Naxxramas solo adventure?

Tags: hearthstone

The first playthrough of the normal mode bosses and the class challenges gives you new cards for your deck(s).
And the first complete playthrough on heroic mode gives you a new card back.

But is there any reason to replay the new solo adventure after you have cleared it one time?

Comment: Bragging rights? I've done it X times bro!

Comment: Blizzard has stated that there will (eventually) be some replay value included in these solo adventures but haven't specified beyond that.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: If you have a source for that and perhaps some more info, that would make a good answer.

Comment: Correction listed here: http://www.hearthpwn.com/blue-tracker/topic/8111-what-is-the-reason-to-replay-the-naxx-content I don't feel it is strong enough for an answer on its own, given that apparently they just meant Heroic Mode.

Comment: So Blizzard also doesn't know why one should replay the naxx bosses after defeating them once ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you'll just earn 6 cards (1 legendary and 5 'commons').

Cards you'll earn :

Haunted Creeper good for a zoo deck (it's a deck with low cost cards and very agressive) you'll earn this if you beat Anub'Rekhan in normal.

Nerub'ar Weblord good for counter battlecry, you'll earn this if you beat Faerlina in normal.

Nerubian Egg it'll combo with a solfurie or an Argus, because if you destroy it, you'll earn a nerubian (it's a 4/4 cards), you'll earn this if you beat Maexxna in normal.

Maexxna she destroy any card she attacked, it can be usefull if you play Anduin Wrynn because he can heal Maexxna. You'll earn this if you beat all the 3 boss in normal and you'll unlock heroic and druid and rogue class challenges.

Poison Seeds : destroy all monsters on the battlefield and give treants 2/2 for each destroyed monster. Can combo with a druid token. Unlock when you finish the druid class challenge.

Anub'ar Ambusher a 5/5 for 4 mana but with a Deathrattle (Return a random friendly monster in your hand) can combo with Si 7. Unlock when you finish the rogue class challenge.

You can find many others information on the wiki : http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Curse_of_Naxxramas

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! We're not a forum, instead we're looking for detailed answers. Do you think you could flesh your answer out a bit?

Comment: Good summary of what you get, but not strictly an answer to my question beyond your first sentence.

Comment: Not only is this a shallow answer it is also plainly incorrect. You earn much more than 6 cards. "Curse of Naxxramas features 30 new collectible cards in total - 21 neutral cards and 9 class-specific cards, one for each class", but this information is not really answering the question of replay value.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the "Win 7 games in any mode" quest, Solo Adventure matches count, which includes Naxxramas.

So if you're just looking for a quick way to win against a known deck, bumrushing Maexxna with a charge deck is gonna be an easy way to get your 7 wins.

Beyond that, there is no reason to replay the wing.

Comment: I think I have never seen that quest (not that I play very much), but good to know if it should pop up.

Comment: @Raidri It's not common, but it is the only quest that rewards 100g!

Comment: its much easier to finish that quest on practice mode though, even easier than fighting maexxna

Answer (score 2):

Currently, no. Once you earn all of the rewards for the quarter, there is no point in going back and replaying them.

I would assume that at some point in the future, people will do races to see who can go through Naxxramas the fastest or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try to challenge yourself with building different kinds of decks that will beat the bosses in heroic mode (or normal mode).

To start with, one deck of each class. If you manage that, you can try imposing other limitations on yourself (only rush, only control, etc.). That way you can make many different interesting challenges. Your imagination is the limit.

Answer (score 2):

How about replaying it for ***fun***? That is why we play games in the first place.

'Replay value' can mean worth generated or entertainment gained. Single player games such as [roguelikes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) have lots of replay value without giving any permanent advantage to the player.

Challenges:

- Use only basic cards. Or only basic+common. Etc. ([credit:Sisk](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/13422992609#6))
- Use your default deck.
- Use random pick deck. (probably not for hard level)
- Complete with every class.
- Complete with only one deck. (choose deck and class at the start)

If you played Naxxramas *just for the cards* of course it will have no replay value.