# Heroic mode Naxxramas

Tags: hearthstone

Does anyone know if there's any point in beating the bosses in the heroic mode?  I'm not interested in a card back so if that's all you get I won't waste my time!

Comment: See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178022/is-there-any-replay-value-in-the-curse-of-naxxramas-solo-adventure?rq=1

Comment: It's a fun challenge! It is a game after all :)

Answer (score 4):

The card back is the only reward you get for beating Naxx heroic.

You also get the pride of knowing that you beat Naxx heroic but you won't get any gold or cards if that's what you're asking.